Are the patterns of light in this arcade game correlated or random?
This comes from a reddit post on r/theydidthemath.
This is a common machine seen in arcades across the world. You try to push the lights as quickly as you can when they light up. Note this video is too large to share here as an embedded video, so hopefully the reddit link is stable (doubtful).

Question
Are the position of the "on" lights correlated more than just being randomly sampled from the inactive lights?
In order to answer this question, we should create a binary matrix of each instance where the lights are on (1 on, 0 off), and see if there's any significant autocorrelation of any lag of the matrix-valued time series.
Note: I could just look up the specs of this machine, but I don't want to proceed this way; I want to purely be able to answer this question from the information given in the video alone.

My idea of attack
We find the pixel position where the lights are on, use the lit up "SPEED of LIGHT" sign as a reference point to correct for the moving camera, and then use ClusterClassify or something similar to convert the corrected pixel positions to light array indices. Once we have a binary array of each frame which indicates which lights are on we look at the AutocorrelationTest of the time series of lights on to see if the lights have any pattern associated with them.

What I've tried so far
We can start by isolating the lights themselves by first using a color filter:
video0 = Import[
   "https://packaged-media.redd.it/02hnynwmcp0e1/pb/m2-res_638p.mp4?m=\
DASHPlaylist.mpd&v=1&e=1731535200&s=\
5ff64fae033697ccbf6115f57903185147ef68a6"];

(*the color of the lights. Found using DominantColors*)
lightColor = RGBColor[
  0.46231571226382845`, 0.8480837001215388, 0.9993233226012449];

(*the bottom weird tiktok stuff is not important*)
video0 = VideoFrameMap[ImageTake[#, 350] &, video0];

(*emphasize the parts of the video that are close to the light color*)
video = VideoFrameMap[ColorDetect[#, ColorsNear[lightColor]] &, video0];

Then delete small components, binarize, and select the ones that are close to circular:
(*emphasize the parts of the video that are close to the light color*)
video = VideoFrameMap[ColorDetect[#, ColorsNear[lightColor]] &, 
   video0];

(*delete small components and binarize*)
video = VideoFrameMap[DeleteSmallComponents[Binarize[#, 0.7], 50] &, 
  video]
(*select components that are very circular*)
video = VideoFrameMap[SelectComponents[#, #Circularity > 1 &] &, 
   video];



Producing this result.
We also need to correct for the non-stationary nature of the camera. I did this by assuming the whole board is approximately equi-distant from the photodetector of the camera, and finding the image text "SPEED of LIGHT" in each frame:
firstFrame = VideoExtractFrames[video0, 0];
refPos = FindImageText[firstFrame, Automatic, "RegionCentroid"]

Then time-index the difference vectors of each frame w.r.t. the reference position:
diffVectors = 
  VideoMapList[({#Time, 
       FindImageText[#Image, Automatic, "RegionCentroid"] - 
        refPos}) &, video0] // Quiet;

And account for the frames where the text was not found (which is what Quiet throws under the rug) and linearly interpolate
diffVectors = DeleteCases[diffVectors, {} + _, Infinity];
id = Interpolation[diffVectors, InterpolationOrder -> 1];

And subtract the difference vectors from the light centroids of each frame (and account for where no lights were found on):
lightCentroids = 
  VideoMapList[{#Time, 
      Values@ComponentMeasurements[#Image, "Centroid"] - 
       Threaded[id[#Time]]} &, video] // Quiet;
lightCentroids = DeleteCases[lightCentroids, {_, {} + Threaded[_]}];

Which generates points that generally look like the outline of the lights in physical space:
ListPlot[lightCentroids[[All, 2]]]



Compare this to the physical outline of the actual lights (one frame of the video):
VideoExtractFrames[video0, 0]



The problem is I have "ghost" columns (I would guess this is from FindImageText not finding the reference text "SPEED of LIGHT" correctly) that are not amenable to now using ClusterClassify to convert the image pixel position to light array indices. So I'm not sure how to proceed now.

Limitations
Note there a lot of limitations given the limited information in this video; the player, for example, gets in the way of some of the lights.
Also, my automated filtering method of just getting a binary video of the "lights" = White, "everything else" = Black is imperfect, as things are misclassified/missed every now and then.

Add-on: here is my own cropped mirror on imgur of the reddit uploaded video. I am not sure if it has worse lossy compression however.

It seems, instead of a full matrix you can track only one bulb state. This will give you a 1d time series to analyze
